# Where do I install the packages wget and unzip for a virtualbox installation script

Tags: shell, npm, scripting, virtualbox

I'm trying to use a script from github to install a virtualbox, but the script depends on wget and unzip. I'm only familiar with installing dependencies via npm or yarn but after installing the script is failing with the message "Please install the packages 'unzip' and 'wget'.". I'm not sure what to install from.

repo using: 
https://github.com/img2tab/macos-guest-virtualbox

edit: host OS is windows, sorry!

Comment: On MacOS? Consider using a package manager like [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/) (my favorite), [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). Even better, once you have one of those, they'll install VirtualBox for you (and take care of upgrading it later, uninstalling it, etc), so you don't need to use random scripts from github.

Comment: ...Macports or Homebrew are specific to MacOS (you didn't tell us what your host OS is!), but Nix will work elsewhere as well. Some operating systems use `apt`, some use `yum` or `rpm` -- it's a very specific to your host, and the question doesn't include details we'd need to provide an answer. (Moreover, "how do I install software?" isn't a question that's meaningfully unique to software development, so it's not particularly topical for Stack Overflow anyhow; our sister site [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is probably a better fit).

Comment: Yeah sorry about posting to Stack Overflow. I'm new to the whole host of sites and wasn't sure which one to use. My host OS is Windows.

Comment: Your link advises you to use Cygwin to install wget and unzip on Windows. You should be able to search for both of them in the Cygwin setup tool's package list.

Comment: You are correct. I ran the installer for Cygwin again and added those packages. Thanks!